# Error creating function--Invalid use of a side-effecting operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code like as below. This is converting IP address into IP names. But I need to add this in function and call in the select statement. But I am getting error like
"Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function."

I tried to add this in Stored procedure, It is working there but I need to put in function so that I can call this in the select query. Any ideas

```
declare @ip as VARCHAR(100)='10.200.11.133'
DECLARE @xpCmd VARCHAR(100)
SET @xpCmd = 'NSLOOKUP ' + @ip
declare @Test table (IPNAME NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Test
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @xpCmd
select LTRIM(REPLACE(IPNAME, 'Name:', '')) IPNAME
FROM @Test
where (IPNAME like 'Name: %')
```

Comment: Basically I am need to pass 10.200.11.133 and get back name--ABC.HGHJSG. Please share any other idea if there is.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using a RDMS to process network related API calls?

Comment: You can't put it in a T-SQL function, period. That's what the error message is telling you. Find another way -- preferably by executing this code on the client side, or else using a CLR function if you really must.

Comment: You can't use a side-effecting command in a function, see the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#interoperability and you *really* shouldn't be doing network access from T-SQL. Use a Powershell or cmd batch script, or a C# app to do this

Comment: The error relates to your `EXEC` keyword. Because User-Defined Functions cannot modify state they're also not allowed to execute stored procedures.